# How to dynamically delete data based on a minimum cutoff value

Tags: vba, excel

I am a geologist working for a small oil company in Louisiana. I constitute our tech department, and unfortunately my experience with coding is quite limited. I have used very basic vba coding in the past, but I dont code that much in my daily job, so I have forgotten most of it. I recently discovered this site, and it has become a great resource to me. I have been able to glean bits and pieces of code from previous answers to previous questions, but I am once again stuck.

I am working on a macro that downloads well production information from the state of Louisiana's DNR and then calculates certain values off of this downloaded data. So far I have the code that retrieves the data, sorts it, and calculates the values that I need.

Now I need to be able to trim this data. Each well will have a different amount of time that it produced oil. Currently my macro extends the formula down to cell 50 (the data will never reach this point. I selected it just to make sure the formula is applied to all cells). Most of the calculated values are 0 I would like to create a macro that deletes all values after the last cell that contains a number of 1 or greater.

The cell containing the data I want to delete is in Cell L

Please let me know if there is anything else you need from me or if I did not explain my problem 
well.

Here is the code that I have generated to calculate the data in Cell L

```
Sub Oil_production_by_year()
'
' Oil_production_by_year Macro
'

'
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Sheets
        ws.Activate

    Range("L2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIFS(RC[-8]:R[2998]C[-8],RC[-11]:R[2998]C[-11],"">=""&RC[8],RC[-11]:R[2998]C[-11],""<=""&RC[9])"
    Range("L2").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2:L51"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("L2:L51").Select
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: If you post what you already have, it would be easier to help.  Your macro, for example. You don't have to limit it to a specific range, if you test how many there are before it runs.

Comment: Alright, I will post it

Comment: Post dummy data for better understanding ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Josiah and a Happy New Year to you.

This code assumes that:

`dataCol` is a reference column of your data which is used to determine the number of rows to autofill your `SUMIFS` formulae.  Currently it is set as col no.5 (col E), so change this to suit your data.

`trimVal` is a variable that holds the value at which the cell values will be deleted. Currently set to 1.

when a formula cell is deleted, any data 'beneath' it in the same column, will be shifted up.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Oil_production_by_year() ' ' Oil_production_by_year Macro '
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim stRow As Long, formulaCol As Long, c As Long
Dim dataCol As Long, dataEndRow As Long, trimVal As Long

stRow = 2
formulaCol = 12
trimVal = 1
'an assumption of colE for the data column
'change this to suit
'means that the formula will only fill the rows reqd
dataCol = 5

For Each ws In Sheets
    With ws
        dataEndRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, dataCol).End(xlUp).Row
        With ws.Cells(stRow, formulaCol)
            .FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=SUMIFS(RC[-8]:R[2998]C[-8],RC[-11]:R[2998]C[-11],"">=""&RC[8],RC[-11]:R[2998]C[-11],""<=""&RC[9])"
            .AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range(ws.Cells(stRow, formulaCol), ws.Cells(dataEndRow, formulaCol)), _
                    Type:=xlFillDefault
        End With

        For c = dataEndRow To stRow Step -1
            If .Cells(c, formulaCol).Value < trimVal Then
                .Cells(c, formulaCol).Delete xlShiftUp
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
    End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Happy New Years!

Comment: @barryleajo, you've been bit faster than me ;) Your solution is almost identitical as mine ;)

Comment: @Maciej Los thanks.  I have one difference which may be important to OP.  My code doesn't delete the entire row, just the 'formula' column.  I figured that any original data needed to be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Still don't know what kind of data you want to delete... I'd suggest to change code as is provided below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Oil_production_by_year()
Dim wsh As Worksheet, iLastCell As Integer, r As Integer

For Each wsh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    iLastCell = GetLastCell(wsh)
    wsh.Range("L2").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(RC[-8]:R[2998]C[-8],RC[-11]:R[2998]C[-11],"">=""&RC[8],RC[-11]:R[2998]C[-11],""<=""&RC[9])"
    wsh.Range("L2").AutoFill Destination:=wsh.Range("L2:L" & iLastCell), Type:=xlFillDefault
    r = iLastCell
    Do While r > 2
        If wsh.Range("L" & r).Value = 0 Then
            'delete entire row
            wsh.Range("L" & r).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
        End If
        If wsh.Range("L" & r).Value > 0 Then Exit Do End If
        r = r - 1
    Loop
Next

End Sub

Function GetLastCell(wsh As Worksheet, Optional sCol As String = "A")
    GetLastCell = wsh.Range(sCol & wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

Change the code to your needs ;)

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Happy New Years!

Comment: @JosiahHulsey, you're very welcome and Happy New Year to You! You can accept my answer if it was helpful ;)